# Jenkins xUnit Plug-in issue

Tags: c++, unit-testing, plugins, jenkins, xunit

I installed Jenkins server (on windows 7), plus xUnit plug-in in order to use UnitTest++ for the C++ project I work on.

I configure jobs scripts so that TestUnit++ produces reports in some directory in the workspace.
But when I activate "Publish testing tools result report", then click on combobox "Add", "UnitTest-1.4", nothing happens. No line is added, nothing actually changes. Same thing with any other choice in "Add" combo box.

Do I use it correctly ?
Is plug-in properly installed ? dependency issue ?
Any other idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Jenkins and the plugin are you using?

Comment: Jenkins is 1.403, xUnit is 1.16.2, Jenkins does not mention about incompatibility...

Comment: Did you restart Jenkins after installing the plugin? There should not be any other dependencies. The only other thing to install is the cppunit plugin if you are using that...can you try 1.404?

Comment: I did restart but the "Add" action still fails. My intention is to use it with UnitTest++ as I read some people do. I'll try Jenkins later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

xUnit requires Jenkins 1.410 or newer according to http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/03/xunit-plugin.html